# jquery click question

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an issue.

the code is this:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
   $("#threads").html("hi");
});
```

when i click the button, the text "hi" is just shown in 1 sec. then it disappear. i want it to always be shown after i have clicked. how can i do this?

Comment: What is the html for #button ?

Comment: Do any other overlapping elements on the page have a click handler? For example, does the body of your document have a click handler?

Comment: @fayer You now have 21 questions inside of 3 days with **no correct answers**. Please take the time to go back and mark the correct answers before asking more questions.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#threads").html("hi");
});
```

My guess is button is an [a href] tag or in a form which is causing the page to refresh.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be that your button is inside a form with no action, thus submitting the form back to the page - and reverting your change. Or that `button` is a link with an empty href.

Add `return false;` to the end of your click-function to stop the default action.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a timeout or interval that is running every 1000 milliseconds, clearing the HTML of #threads. Either it's running as a timeout (setTimeout) from another `$("#button").click()` or an interval (setInterval) defined somewhere else. I'm just guessing 1000 milliseconds because you said 1 second and I don't know if you mean for a moment instead.

Comment: i mean for a moment. when i just type $("#threads").html("hi"); it works just fine...i think it has something to do with the click function?

Comment: We'd have to probably see more of the code to understand your problem better.